# Kinect precision curves for 2 Kinects in the wiki?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/openni_kinect/kinect_accuracy

In the first graph there is a second pair of curves labeled "2 Kinects". What does it represent? I am interested in checking/reproducing these values with several sensor systems.

Thanks for enlighting me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196117/kinect-precision-curves-for-2-kinects-in-the-wiki?/) by [mh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20605/mh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm fairly certain that they are referring to a situation where 2 Kinects are both looking at the plane at the same time. The projected patterns from the Kinects interfere with each other, and the data obtained from either Kinect is likely to be noisier. [Here is a PDF](http://webee.technion.ac.il/%7Elihi/Teaching/2012_winter_048921/PPT/Roy.pdf) of a presentation discussing the issue, and some possible remedies. Specifically, see page 20 for examples of a scene with multiple Kinects interfering. Microsoft published a paper on the *Shake ‘n’ Sense*, a very cool technique for helping to eliminate the interference. Here's a [demo video](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/video/default.aspx?id=160616&r=1).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20605/mh/) on 2014-11-11**:
Thank you very much for this explanation and the additional helpful information!